# How to fix error "The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to retrieve an image from firebase storage. I was following a YouTube tutorial and the error was on the **snapshot.data** saying **The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget?'**.

Please help me to fix this error. Thank you so much.

````
final String image1 = "images/image0.png";
final String image2 = "images/image0.png";

String image = image1;

class LoadFirebaseStorageImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoadFirebaseStorageImage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); ```
````

```
            Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: _getImage(context, image),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                      return Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.25,
                          child: snapshot.data);
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                      return Container(
                          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.25,
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    return Container();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      loadButton(context),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}```

Comment: What you have inside ->snapshot.data ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to indicate the type of the snapshot at the FutureBuilder, like

```
FutureBuilder<Widget>(
```

This is assuming that `_getImage` returns a `Widget`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you have parsed `snapshot.data` directly to the widget. You can not pass the data directly to the widget.
first, check what are you getting on `snapshot.data` by `printing` it.
if you are getting the network URL of the image then you can use it like below.

you will always get some data not `widget` in `snapshot.data`.
just check what are you getting `print` function.

```
       Container(
          height: double.infinity,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, top: 10),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: _getImage(context, image),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                print(snapshot.data);

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
                  return Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.25,
                      child: Image.network(snapshot.data));
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                  return Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.25,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.25,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                return Container();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```